# Iterating over and formatting an array field with meteor and mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor

Say I have mongodb collection called "people", and the following documents are inside the people collection:

```
{
  name: "James",
  aliases: ["Jim", "Jimmy", "Jimbo", "Jamie"]
}

{
  name: "Mary",
  aliases: ["Mae", "May", "Molly", "Mimi"]
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to write the aliases array for each document in an HTML element, and also format them with spaces.

Doing this: ***[EDITED] I had given a bad example***

```
<p>{{aliases}}</p>
```

results in listing the names like

> "Jim,Jimmy,Jimbo,Jamie"

. Is there a way I can make it result in

> "Jim, Jimmy, Jimbo, Jamie"

with spaces instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `{{aliases}}`, the *compiler* will set the `array` as value for `innerHTML` property and the array will be automatically coerced to `string`.

When we're using `.toString()` method for one `array` it's invoked *automatically* `join` method with *default* delimiter = `','`

Use this:

```
{{aliases.join', '}}
```

*Syntax edited*

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want, but when I use it in my actual project my app crashes and gives me this error: "While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser):
client/main.html:44: Expected IDENTIFIER
..."tags">{{genres.join(', ')}}</span>" genres would be equivalent to aliases in my question.

Comment: I've found the issue. The syntax that worked is a bit different than what you suggested. {{aliases.join', '}} fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @GarrettSmith, great! I never worked with `meteor` but I was sure that the solution is to use `join` method because render it's working like in `React` or `Angular`.

Comment: Please edit my answer with your solution :  `{{aliases.join', '}} ` in order to help other people in future.